# Naming union or boost::variant typedefs

Tags: c++

I'm holding database values in a variant. Which of the following typedefs makes most sense in your opinion:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, std::string> Value;
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, std::string> Values;
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, std::string> Type;
typedef boost::variant<int, bool, std::string> Types;
```

Answer (score 3):

None of them have meaning. What means Values or Types? Just abstract names. Better name them with more concrete for example as ObjectState or PacketField. Such names as Type means nothing, when you name your variable think that other people could read and understand what it means and when you forget what did you do you must remember what it is and dont read bunch of code to understand what this type for.

For more information about variables naming and more about software engineering you can buy wonderful book [Code complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) written by [Steve McConnell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_McConnell).

Comment: One could argue that ObjectState and PacketField hardly have any more meaning than Value/Type.... they are just longer.